# How can plot Artists be reused (Line2D)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can the plot lines from `.plot` be reused in subsequent plots?

I'd like to make plots on 4 axes, first three individual plot on each axes, and the last all 3 plots on last axes.
Here is the code:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
fig=figure()
data=arange(0,10,0.01)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax4=fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)

line1=ax1.plot(data,data)
line2=ax2.plot(data, data**2/10, ls='--', color='green')
line3=ax3.plot(data, np.sin(data), color='red')
#could I somehow use previous plots, instead recreating them all?
line4=ax4.plot(data,data)
line4=ax4.plot(data, data**2/10, ls='--', color='green')
line4=ax4.plot(data, np.sin(data), color='red')
show()
```

The resulting picture is:
[image]
Is there a way to define plots first and then add them to axes, and then plot them? Here is the logic I had in mind:

```
#this is just an example, implementation can be different
line1=plot(data, data)
line2=plot(data, data**2/10, ls='--', color='green')
line3=plot(data, np.sin(data), color='red')
line4=[line1, line2, line3]
```

Now plot line1 on ax1, line2 on ax2, line3 on ax3 and line4 on ax4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The requested implementation in the OP doesn't work because the [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) plot Artist returned by [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) can't be reused. Trying to do so, will result in a `RuntimeError` as per [`def set_figure(self, fig):`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/artist.html#Artist.set_figure)

  - `line1` in the OP, is not the same as `line1` created directly with the `Line2D` method, because a plotted Artist has different properties.
  - In regards to `seaborn`, and API for `matplotlib`, axes-level plots like [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) return an `axes`:

    - `p = sns.lineplot(...)` then `p.get_children()` to get the Artist objects.
- Plot artists can be created directly, with methods like [`matplotlib.lines.Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html), and reused in multiple plots.
- Updated code using standard importing practices, subplots, and not using a list-comprehension for a side-effect (a python anti-pattern).
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
import numpy as np
from copy import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

# crate the figure and subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# flatten axes into 1-D for easy indexing and iteration
axes = axes.ravel()

# test data
data=np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)

# create test lines
line1 = Line2D(data, data)
line2 = Line2D(data, data**2/10, ls='--', color='green')
line3 = Line2D(data, np.sin(data), color='red')
lines = [line1, line2, line3]

# add the copies of the lines to the first 3 subplots
for ax, line in zip(axes[0:-1], lines):
    ax.add_line(copy(line))

# add 3 lines to the 4th subplot
for line in lines:
    axes[3].add_line(line)
    
# autoscale all the subplots if needed
for _a in axes:
    _a.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Original Answer

- Here is one possible solution. I'm not sure that it's very pretty, but at least it does not require code duplication.

```py
import numpy as np, copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.lines as ml

fig=plt.figure(1)
data=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax4=fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)

#create the lines
line1=ml.Line2D(data,data)
line2=ml.Line2D(data,data**2/10,ls='--',color='green')
line3=ml.Line2D(data,np.sin(data),color='red')
#add the copies of the lines to the first 3 panels
ax1.add_line(copy.copy(line1))
ax2.add_line(copy.copy(line2))
ax3.add_line(copy.copy(line3))

[ax4.add_line(_l) for _l in [line1,line2,line3]] # add 3 lines to the 4th panel

[_a.autoscale() for _a in [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]] # autoscale if needed
plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your usage is fine, but you can pass all of the `x,y` data pairs to `plot` like this (although it makes it very horrible to read!):

```
ax4.plot(data, data, data, data**2 / 10, data, np.sin(data))
```

An amusing different way to do it is like this:

```
graph_data = [(data, data), (data, data**2 / 10), (data, np.sin(data))]
[ax4.plot(i,j) for i,j in graph_data]
```

Comment: I usually do things the wrong way, I must be getting better. :) I upvoted both solutions, the selection for accepted answer was arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

I had a simpler use case in jupyter notebooks. Given that you have stored a figure object somewhere, how can you replot it.
eg:

Cell 1:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
f.suptitle("Hierarchical Clustring", fontsize=20)
dendrogram(Z, color_threshold=cut_off,
           truncate_mode='lastp',
           p=20)
```

Cell 2:

```
#plot f again, the answer is really simple
f
plt.show()
```

That's it. The benefit of that is you can store figures in objects and later use them when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162443/why-do-many-examples-use-fig-ax-plt-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot-python) has a good example of referencing to previous axes using:

```
fix, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax[0,1].plot(data, data**2 / 10, ls='--', color='g')
```

but also explains how to insert a title on each subplot using:

```
ax[0,1].set_title('Simple plot')
```

the dimension of ax depends on subplot parameters: if they are just tiled orizontally or vertically, ax will only need one index.