# fig and ax properties in matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Which object contains the property `ylim()`? In the code below (I have imported the required packages and `x1` and `y1` plot properly) to set the y-axis limits, I have to use `plt.ylim()`, why is this so? In my own head, I would use `ax1.ylim()` because the y-axis belongs to an ax object instance. Can someone please explain why this is not correct?

I saw this post here:

[Why do many examples use "fig, ax = plt.subplots()" in Matplotlib/pyplot/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162443/why-do-many-examples-use-fig-ax-plt-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot-python)

which helped clarify it a little, but I'm still unsure.
Thanks!

```
x1 = df_mstr1['datetime'].values
y1 = df_mstr1['tons'].values
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.stackplot(x1, y1, color='blue')
plt.ylim(0,300)
fig1.savefig('page.pdf', format = 'pdf')
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but you can use `ax.set_ylim((lower, upper))` to set the limits (http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim). `matplotlib` encourages two different styles of usage, which you can read more about at (http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles). Mixing both styles is (in my experience) not a good idea.

Comment: That's an answer of a comment. If you post that as a reply I would mark it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_ylim((lower, upper))` to set the limits (http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim).

`matplotlib` encourages two different styles of usage. An OO-style that offers maximum flexibility and a matlab-style making heavy use of global state. The latter is useful for quick interactive exploration, the former is the way to go for production-ready fine tuned plots.

You can read more about that [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles).

I recommend sticking to one style, as mixing both leads to trouble (at least that's what I experienced)

Answer (score 5):

The way I think about it is that `pyplot.ylim()` is the convenience function (it's not technically a property) providing a MATLAB-like functionality to set the y-limits of the *current* axes (the one most recently created or plotted on), whereas `ax1.set_ylim()` sets the y-limits of a specific axes object (there could be more than one) which you have named `ax1`.

`plt.ylim()` is good for quick plots that don't require much customization. The more object-oriented `ax1.set_ylim()` is better when you need to keep track of more objects related to your plot in order to customize them (and keep track of what you've customized) more clearly.