# Python: plot multiple plts to file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

With `savefig('foo.pdf')` or `savefig('foo.png')`, it seems like we can only plot one thing to one file (`foo.png` or `foo.pdf`) at a time. Is there a way to plot multiple images to the same file, one after another?

I need something like this:

```
for center in centers:
    plt.imshow(center.reshape(28, 28))
    plot/save this current image to file, all in the same file
```

So I just want all of the reshaped, 28 by 28 images contained in the `centers` list in the same file.
For many months, I've had to `plt.show()` each image, take screenshots of those individual images, and then crop and paste them into one file. But this obviously doesn't scale.

Comment: Typically we would use [`subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want several images on one page, you're looking for `plt.subplots`, [Why do many examples use "fig, ax = plt.subplots()" in Matplotlib/pyplot/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162443/why-do-many-examples-use-fig-ax-plt-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot-python)

If you want a multipage PDF document, there's PDF backend:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html