# matplotlib plt.show() doesn't show anything if axis is added after defining figure

Tags: matplotlib

I have a problem with plotting through matplotlib.

When I try to plot with this code works well:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(10)
plt.show()
```

But when I try this one, doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(10)
plt.show()
```

Does someone know why this happens?

My matplotlib version is 3.3.4

Many thanks.

Comment: "doesn't work" is pretty vague.  However pyplot does not have a `Figure` method, I think you mean `plt.figure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at the second line of your second code snippet, you're capitalizing the letter "f" in `plt.Figure`, it should be `plt.figure` instead. Bellow is the corrected version:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(10)
plt.show()
```

Your output will be:

[image]

Comment: It works well, thank you! I have one remaining (not important) question that why does it seems fig and ax are created normally (I can even access line values which I assigned to ax)?

Comment: `plt.Figure` is a class, not a method. `plt.figure()` is a method (function) which creates an instance of the `Figure` class. So in your version that doesn't work, you are creating a `Figure`, but probably not initialising all the elements of it that are needed to properly display it.

Comment: @Hayoung, look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162641/14195255 its very well explained.