# python subplot command is not working correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to create 9 subplots in a 3 by 3 format in python but even though plenty of code samples exist online of the exact arguments i'm inputing exist, for some reason pyCharm insists on needing either 1 or 3 arguments rather than 2:

```
fig, plot_order = plot.subplot(3,3)
```

the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: subplot() takes 1 or 3 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Comment: Python itself doesn't make plots; please identify the module(s) you are using to do this.

Comment: [The documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) for matplolib's subplot method gives information about calling it with 3 and calling it with 1 but not calling it with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

replace the "subplot" with "subplots" like this:

```
fig, plot_order = plot.subplots(3,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html), one needs to either use a three-digit integer (like **234**) or three integers (like **2, 3, 4**) to decide the position of the subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a 3*3 arrangement and draw subplots with indices 1 and 2
fig1 = plt.subplot(331)
fig2 = plt.subplot(332)
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

The white space in the figure above shows that we have the blueprint to plot other subplots in the 3*3 arrangement, but we haven't explicitly told matplotlib to draw them. Indexing starts from 1 and refers to the top-left subplot in the figure.

This can be utilised to create subplots with different sizes e.g.

```
fig3 = plt.subplot(331)
fig4 = plt.subplot(122)
plt.show()
```

gives:

[image]

Another way to get a *m * n* subplots arrangement is to use the arguments *nrows* and *ncols* of [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to get desired numbers of rows and columns in the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)
```

which gives:
[image]

If you are just getting started with matplotlib, you might wonder why `plt.subplot` returns one object and `plt.subplots` returns two. To understand that, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162641/7789963) and to learn more about matplotlib, please check the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html).