# Matplotlib copy/duplicate a 3D figure?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've tried to find a way to copy a 3D figure in matplotlib but I didn't find a solution which is  appropriate in my case.

From these posts 
[How do I reuse plots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499482/how-do-i-reuse-plots-in-matplotlib)
and 
[How to combine several matplotlib figures into one figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521560/how-to-combine-several-matplotlib-figures-into-one-figure)
Using `fig2._axstack.add(fig2._make_key(ax),ax)` as in the code below gives quite the good result but figure 2 is not interactive I can't rotate the figure etc :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

ax.plot([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
fig2._axstack.add(fig2._make_key(ax),ax)

plt.show()
```

An alternative would be to copy objects from ax to ax2 using a copy method proposed in this post [How do I reuse plots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499482/how-do-i-reuse-plots-in-matplotlib) but executing the code below returns `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure` :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np, copy

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

ax.plot([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax2 = fig2.gca(projection = '3d')

for n in range(len(ax.lines)) :
    ax2.add_line(copy.copy(ax.lines[n]))
plt.show()
```

Those codes are pretty simple but I don't want to copy/paste part of my code for drawing similar figures

Thanks in advance for your reply !

Comment: Instead of copy-pasting code, why not just write a function which takes an `ax` object as argument and call that function twice with two different `Axes` objects?

Comment: Yes that would be an "easy" solution but in the case you have a very long plot like a 3d surface or a complicated function, run multiple times this function isn't a "good" solution. Thanks anyway !